# DRF: How to validate a nested serializer's fields?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have `models` as below:

```
model: Business
    name

model: Employee
    business=FK(Business),
    user = FK(User)

model: Item
    title
    units

model: PurchaseInvoice
    business=FK(Business)
    employee = FK(Employee)
    invoice_no
    date

model: PurchasedItems
    parent_invoice=FK(PurchaseInvoice, related_name="purchased_items")
    item = FK(Item)
    quantity
    rate
```

and `serializers.py`:

```
class PurchasedItemPOSTSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PurchasedItem
        fields = ('item', 'quantity', 'rate')

    def validate_quantity(self, value):
        if value==0 or value is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid quantity")
        return value

    def validate_rate(self, value):
        if value==0 or value is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("rate?? Did you get it for free?")
        return value



class PurchaseInvoicePOSTSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    purchased_items = PurchasedItemPOSTSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseInvoice
        fields = ('invoice_no','date','purchased_items')

    def validate_purchased_items(self, value):
        if len(value)==0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("atleast one item is required.")
        return value

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        purchased_items_data = validated_data.pop('purchased_items')
        purchase_invoice = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for purchased_item in purchased_items_data:
            PurchasedItem.objects.create(purchase_invoice=purchase_invoice, **purchased_item)
        return invoice
```

and `views.py`

```
class PurchaseInvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PurchaseInvoicePOSTSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'user': self.request.user, 'business_id': self.kwargs['business_id']}

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return PurchaseInvoice.objects.filter(business__id=self.kwargs['business_id'])

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        business = Business.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['business_id'])
        employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, business=business, user=self.request.user)
        serializer.save(business=business, employee=employee)
```

The data sent through POST is:

```
{
    "invoice_no": "123",
    "date": "2018-07-13",
    "purchased_items": [
    {"item":1, "quantity":0, "rate":0}],
}
```

As you can see from the data above no error is raised by `validate_quantity` when `quantity=0` and neither by `validate_rate` when `rate=0` for the `item` in `purchased_items`.

Comment: Can you add the corresponding view class?

Comment: @JPG updated please check.

Comment: Can you also add the PurchasedItems and PurchaseInvoice model?

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52357289/5710526

Answer (score -2):

You can add custom validate in your serializer. For example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
    class PurchasedItemPOSTSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = PurchasedItem
            fields = ('item', 'quantity', 'rate')

        def validate(self, data):
            # custom anything validate
            quantity = data.get('quantity')
            # recheck validate in this
            if not quantity:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('not valid')
            return data
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I have already added validation above. But that is not invoked.

Comment: Sure, your validate_rate or validate_quantity will not invoked. But My validate not is like this. It is custom validate and always invoke when method serializer.is_valid() call.Pls try

Comment: the order of validation in a serializer is: `validate_<field>` then `validate`. And anyway I have solved it already. Thanks.