# Django Rest Framework: How to pass data to a nested Serializer and create an object only after custom validation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have two models as:

```
class Book(AppModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Link(AppModel):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Page(AppModel):
    book= models.ForeignKey("Book", related_name="pages", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link = models.ForeignKey("Link", related_name="pages", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page_no = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()
```

and `serializers`

```
class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Link
       fields = ['link']

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('link','text','page_no')

    def validate_text(self, value):
        #some validation is done here.

    def validate_link(self, value):
        #some validation is done here.

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pages = PageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title','pages')

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        pages_data= validated_data.pop('pages')
        book = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for page_data in pages_data:
            Page.objects.create(book=book, **page_data)
        return book
```

There is a `validate_text` method in `PageSerializer`. The `create` method will never call the `PageSerializer` and the `page_data` is never validated.

So I tried another approach as:

```
@transaction.atomic
def create(self, validated_data):
    pages_data = validated_data.pop('pages')
    book = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for page_data in pages_data:
        page = Page(book=book)
        page_serializer = PageSerializer(page, data = page_data)
        if page_serializer.is_valid():
            page_serializer.save()
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(page_serializer.errors)
    return book
```

Posted data:

```
{
    "title": "Book Title",
    "pages": [
        {
            "link": 1, "page_no": 52, "text": "sometext"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the above approach throws error:

```
{
    "link": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received Link."
    ]
}
```

I also found why this error is caused: Though I am posting data with `pk` value `1` of a `Link`, the data when passed to the `PageSerializer` from the `BookSerializer` appears as such: `{"link": "/go_to_link/", "page_no":52, "text": "sometext"}`

Why is an instance of `Link` passed to the `PageSerializer` whereas what I sent is `pk` of `Link`?

Comment: `PageSerializer` expects a `Comment` instance whereas you are passing a `Page` instance

Comment: @JPG sorry that's a mistake. It's the `Page` instance. These aren't my actual code. Just used for explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To validate a nested object using a nested serializer:

```
@transaction.atomic
def create(self, validated_data):
    pages_data = validated_data.pop('pages') #pages data of a book
    book= self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for page_data in pages_data:
        page = Page(book=book)
        page_serializer = PageSerializer(page, data = page_data)
        if page_serializer.is_valid(): #PageSerializer does the validation
            page_serializer.save()
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(page_serializer.errors) #throws errors if any
    return book
```

Suppose you send the data as:

```
{
    "title": "Book Title",
    "pages": [{
        "link":2,#<= this one here
        "page_no":52, 
        "text":"sometext"}]
}
```

In the above data we are sending an `id` of the `Link` object. But in the `create` method  of the `BookSerializer` defined above, the data we sent changes to:

```
{
    "title": "Book Title",
    "pages": [{
        "link":Link Object (2),#<= changed to the Link object with id 2
        "page_no":52, 
        "text":"sometext"}]
}
```

And the `PageSerializer` is actually meant to receive an `pk` value of the `link` i.e, `"link": 2` instead of `"link":Link Object (2)`. Hence it throws error:

`{
"link": [
    "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received Link."
    ]
}`

So the workaround is to override the `to_internal_value` method of the nested serializer to convert the received `Link Object (2)` object to its `pk` value.

So your `PageSerializer` class should then be:

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('link','text','page_no')

    def to_internal_value(self, data): 
        link_data = data.get("link")
        if isinstance(link_data, Link): #if object is received
            data["link"] = link_data.pk # change to its pk value
        obj = super(PageSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        return obj

    def validate_text(self, value):
        #some validation is done here.

    def validate_link(self, value):
        #some validation is done here.
```

and the parent serializer:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pages = PageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title','pages')

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        pages_data = validated_data.pop('pages')#pages data of a book
        book= self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for page_data in pages_data:
            page = Page(book=book)
            page_serializer = PageSerializer(page, data = page_data)
            if page_serializer.is_valid(): #PageSerializer does the validation
                page_serializer.save()
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(page_serializer.errors) #throws errors if any
        return book
```

That should allow the nested serializer to do the validation instead of writing validation inside the create method of the parent serializer and violating DRY.

Comment: Do you find any official source of why it happens? I also have the same problem. Pass the pk as an integer in the request data. When it goes to the validated_data, it turns into an object. 

It takes me a day to find this thread but I don't understand why it happens for nested serializers.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True/False)` it automatically call validate functions of nested serializer. When you call `serializer.save(**kwargs)` serializer passes validated data into your `create(self, validated_data)` or `update(self, instance, validated_data)` functions of serializer. Moreover, in validated data your ForeignKey fields returned an object.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    pages_data = validated_data.pop('pages') # [{'link': Linkobject, ...}]
    book= self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for page_data in pages_data:
        page = Page(book=book)
        page_serializer = PageSerializer(page, data = page_data) # here you are sending object to validation again
        if page_serializer.is_valid():
            page_serializer.save()
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(page_serializer.errors)
    return book
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. When data is passed to a nested serializer within a serializer, if there is any field with `id`, the `id` is never passed instead object related to that id is passed over. And how to overcome this? How to pass the `id` instead of `object`?

Comment: In order to do this you should define link as integer field  in `PageSerializer` like `id=serializers.IntegerField()`

Comment: That's not the case. Instead of writing validation in the current serializer while creating the `pages` in the `book`, it would be more DRY way if I could use the validation of the `PageSerializer` itself.

And moreover, the problem here is `id` is never passed to the nested serializer. Instead the object itself is passed even if I post an `id` to the parent serializer.

Comment: In that case you need not overrides, your first definition of serializers is enough. if you want to make sure you can debug your first defined serializer validations. When you call `BookSerializer`s save method it calls save method with validated data, even page_data is validated.

Comment: The validators are ok. I have already debugged everything. Please check the question. The debugging part is at the bottom.

Comment: For nested serializers you should handle create and update by yourself. You can see it in [django rest framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers). As I mention above when you call `BookSerializer(**kwargs).is_valid()` it call `PageSerializer` validation functions